# Check whether the variable product is virtual or physical

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to check whether the variables of a product are virtual or physical? The code below is just to distinguish simple virtual products from simple physical products.

```
function customize_wp_head() {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->is_virtual() ) {
        echo 'is virtual';
    } else {
        echo 'is physical';
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'customize_wp_head' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is_virtual() method belongs to WC_Product class so WC_Product_Variation class has this method too:

https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html#method_is_virtual